# Getting max count from a view

Tags: sql, oracle, view, count, max

I created a view that allows me to view the number of appointments a doctor has.

view code:

```
create view DocApps as
select d.doctorid, d.surname ||','|| d.given as "Doctor", count(*) as "Appointments"
from doctor d, appointment
where d.doctorid=appointment.doctorid
group by d.doctorid, d.surname, d.given;
```

and I now need to show the doctor with the most appointments, and I have used this code, as it has worked in previous queries:

```
select Doctor, Appointments
from docapps
where Appointments in (select max(Appointments)
from docapps);
```

but it is returning with "Appointments" : invalid identifier, when I have specified that it is that?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: drop the double quotes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628412/enclosing-column-names-within-double-quoatation-marks-with-create-command-in-ora) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using double quotes (`"`) would make object names such as tables and columns case-sensitive, which is what leads to your problem. Just drop them from the view declaration and you should be fine:

```
CREATE VIEW DocApps AS
SELECT   d.doctorid, d.surname ||','|| d.given AS Doctor, 
         COUNT(*) AS Appointments
FROM     doctor d, appointment
WHERE    d.doctorid=appointment.doctorid
GROUP BY d.doctorid, d.surname, d.given;
```